# is it possible to set Outlook 2007 Startup Folder through PRF?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

I have a PRF that will automatically configure an IMAP account in Outlook is it possible to set the Startup Folder also through the PRF?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. The setting belongs to Outlook, not profiles.

Comment: if thats the case is there a way for me to set the outlook settings automatically during the first login? thanks